# How to create a dynamic array to pass into function that takes in `int64_t const *` type?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm working with a codebase where there's a function with the following declaration:

```
int process(int64_t const *dimensions, int64_t size);
```

I'm working with a function that calls `process` and the argument that I pass into `process` is an array of dimensions, but the size of the array can only be determined at runtime, all the values are the same.

I need a way to write

```
int64_t dimensions[N] = {1};
```

where `N` is determined at runtime. Is there a possible way to do this and have it be compatible with the parameter for `process`?

Comment: Why can't you heap-allocate it?

Comment: Why use pointers? C++ has `std::vector`.

Comment: @kiner_shah I don't have any say in how `process` was designed''

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I can do that. Can I use smart pointers here to create the argument or is there no implicit conversion available from smart pointers to raw pointer?

Comment: @user5965026, ohk yeah, it's another code base, my bad :-) But, maybe if that function is called from somewhere else in the code, then you can find the usage of that function by a simple search and see how it is used.

Comment: You can use `std::vector<int64_t> v(N);` and access its internal array using `v.data()` ie. `process(v.data());`.

Comment: @Galik Ohh great, thanks. I didn't know that was possible

Comment: If you want to pass a pointer to an array of `N` values that each have a value of `1`, try `std::vector<int64_t> v (N, 1);  process(v.data());`.    There is still the outstanding problem that `process()` has no way to detect when it has reached the last element unless `N` is passed in some other manner.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I forgot to mention process has a second parameter denoting the size of the input array. I edited that in to the OP

Comment: You still can use `std::vector<int64_t> v(N, 1);`. Either you call `process(v.data(), 1);` or (even more maintenance friendly) `process(v.data(), v.size());`. Please, note that the call of `v.data()` may result in Undefined Behavior if the size can become 0 at any chance. In that case: `if (v.size()) process(v.data(), v.size());` or `process(v.size() ? v.data() : nullptr, v.size());`.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat it's implementation defined whether it is a null pointer or not, but [`data()`; `data() + size()`) is a valid range.

Comment: @Caleth I must admit I wasn't completely sure whether it's U.B. or not. However, whenever I call `std::vector::data()` in VS2013 while `size()` is 0, I get these annoying `assert()`s out of the impl. Hence, I thought it couldn't hurt to check this. I see, [std::vector<T,Allocator>::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) "proves" you right. ;-)